# I cant display 3 cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift

```
switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell", for: indexPath)
             return cell
        case 1:
            let cell2 = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell2", for: indexPath)
            return cell2
        default:
            let cell3 = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell3", for: indexPath)
            return cell3
}
```

Comment: did you assign datasource & delegate to your `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Please add more details so people can help you.

Comment: try `indexPath.item` instead?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UICollectionViewCell
 {
    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell", for: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

> For number of item

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
  return 3
}
```

> For Get 3 cell in one row

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize 
    {
       let yourWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/3.0
       let yourHeight = yourWidth

       return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't understand what you want exactly but try this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = UICollectionViewCell()
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell1 = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell", for: indexPath)
             cell = cell1
             break
        case 1:
            let cell2 = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell2", for: indexPath)
            cell = cell2
             break
        default:
            let cell3 = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "formCell3", for: indexPath)
            cell = cell3
            break
    }
    return cell
}
```